# Pandas with sharing x axis and incomplete data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having trouble with making a ranking graph using Pandas where some of the data could be new and only has data starting halfway between my data's date range.

Below is some test data and an image showing the problems. For one, the X labels seem to be derived from the last call to plot and secondly, the data with missing data on the first day is plotted 1 day left of where I would want it.

How can I fix this plot so the "Recent" line is shifted over correctly and the dates on the X axis are also correct?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

TESTDATA=StringIO("""
2017-10-10  A   30
2017-10-10  B   40
2017-10-10  C   60
2017-10-10  D   20

2017-10-11  A   60
2017-10-11  B   20
2017-10-11  C   30
2017-10-11  D   10
2017-10-11  Recent  50

2017-10-12  A   40
2017-10-12  B   20
2017-10-12  C   17
2017-10-12  D   15
2017-10-12  Recent  45
""")

# recent 

headers = ['Date','Name','Downloads']
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep='\t', names=headers)
df["Ranking"] = df.groupby(["Date"])["Downloads"].rank(method="first", ascending=False)
print(df)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), sharex=True)
labels = []

for key, grp in df.groupby(['Name']):
    #grp = grp[grp.Ranking <=3]
    grp.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', y='Ranking', linewidth=4, sharex=True)
    labels.append(key)
lines, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(lines, labels, loc='best')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis
#ax.set_ylim(4.5, 0.5)

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Rank')
plt.title('Daily Download Ranks')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```
df.pivot('Date','Name','Downloads').rank(method="first", ascending=False,axis=1).plot()
```

[image]